# Umbraco RoleProvider error

Tags: .net, umbraco, umbraco6

I'm facing a web.config error on my Umbraco 6.2.1 website on production server.

I have no issue running this site on my dev computer.

An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

```
<providers>
<clear/>
<add name="UmbracoRoleProvider" type="Umbraco.Web.Security.Providers.MembersRoleProvider" />
</providers>
</roleManager>
```

Comment: I was receiving a similar error after the global start up had failed due to permissions, but someone else was making a request first, and seeing the start up error relating to permissions, where as I saw all penultimate requests just showing a random Umbraco Role Provider error.

Comment: the error can be due to permissions on prod, can you tell the exact error you see.